# Exclude specific object items from intellisense

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this reduce function

```
export const formatData = ({
  datapoints = [],
  resolution = 0,
  operation = 'average',
}: {
  datapoints: Datapoint[]
  resolution: number
  operation: 'summ' | 'average'
}) =>
  datapoints.reduce<{
    time: string[]
    formattedConsumption: number[]
    formattedGeneration: number[]
    formattedSelfCoverage: number[]
  }>(
    (obj, { consumption, time, generation, self_coverage }, i) => {
      if (i % resolution === 0) {
        if (i === 0) {
          obj.tempConsumption = +consumption
          obj.tempGeneration = +generation
          obj.tempSelfCoverage = +self_coverage
        }
        if (datapoints[i + 1] === undefined) {
          obj.tempConsumption = +consumption
          obj.tempGeneration = +generation
          obj.tempSelfCoverage = +self_coverage
        }
        obj.formattedConsumption.push(
          operation === 'average'
            ? obj.tempConsumption / resolution
            : obj.tempConsumption
        )
        obj.formattedGeneration.push(
          operation === 'average'
            ? obj.tempGeneration / resolution
            : obj.tempGeneration
        )
        obj.formattedSelfCoverage.push(
          operation === 'average'
            ? obj.tempSelfCoverage / resolution
            : obj.tempSelfCoverage
        )
        obj.tempConsumption = +consumption
        obj.tempGeneration = +generation
        obj.tempSelfCoverage = +self_coverage

        obj.time.push(dayjs(time).format('D.M HH:mm'))
        return obj
      }

      obj.tempConsumption = +consumption
      obj.tempGeneration = +generation
      obj.tempSelfCoverage = +self_coverage
      return obj
    },
    {
      time: [],
      formattedConsumption: [],
      formattedGeneration: [],
      formattedSelfCoverage: [],
      tempConsumption: 0,
      tempGeneration: 0,
      tempSelfCoverage: 0,
    }
  )
```

VS code says:

> Property 'tempConsumption' does not exist on type '{ time: string[];
> formattedConsumption: number[]; formattedGeneration: number[];
> formattedSelfCoverage: number[]; }'.

Here is my intellisense

[image]

I want to remove this 3 `temp` datas from my intellisense. So i only see the formatted data and `time`

How do i do this with typescript?

Here is an typescript playground link: [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgCYgMYBsCGMQI5gZwIQBFM5NoBLAO0QG9gEEdMkob0BPBOKgWxAB+AFwICcGLQDmCAD4IaAV3ToA3ExYg2Hbng4El-CHw6jxkmfMUr1m1u049pIGiBjkqZsRKk1ZCsqqGswOujwEIOgAZgD6qFAAbu6YLua+VoG2GgC+wPmgkLCICTQSCNGw-ORkFAgAvAgAFIzMSOSUULRwxI0A2gC6ADT2IARQ6EqmNA0IAAwjzFAQKdOzAOSYyR4u6yM5Yq3IHdR0BGK1nd2Do+OT02LK-ABG7prLq140YuuG-PzraybbapEDrYA5ACUDQAfJp2hRTj0AHQ4JBKVAgJqaZhNKDPABWQwQ9H0ZSMJi+xJcbg802JkRi8SSKRcCByxKo0PqMJJOOYAoQVGiTQAhKU-pSOPIFKKaZ9pXJZYy4gkQS5oTg4EoYDN8QT+cxhc0qAgAKRaO5TL4NeqNObQo6CgWGgXGpqmu32x2uwX65FwEDGADCBgpa0aAGoJeGvr6Bf7A8YAOKuBUzKPyulx53OxNBiAAZSi0VD6twUZVzPL8byuaN0WaCKuZz6psjCAAjANbY0lDQUNFaCAkD76wnCQGC6HycYIwho2G5znxwh8ym09npZnN54OPGlpOk0WS2XWRWF1W1efa-H-ZUYNU4IGkDPJdNkRAlAQABbY1drisW4ZnaCDAue4IAcwQhrke05LlKMwAPSWhM1r7lBCBiOuEBvrGGH1pCd6Tg+T4vqmtJ7jQn7fn+B6AemvZgVsEH0dBsEElOG6UWsKE4Fa0xsVhHFcRAFHpvGRHjveVTkC+xYxGeOwgDRv7-quHzAUx4HKZBUEwThCmliyykIHxYxoYJmHYXBxhGUpoKScRnHHnhy7bguMbuTQzmieJWk7jxK65oZp4maCsyRle4UuPk45IUhiYCCpX5qe0XAEgQTR8IIkLIqR5BNOsJDIgAsggAASFUiP86yQlJ9ZajqeqEq6eSujhbmIbMnkIVZea2WJu7zpGWZUR1g32TFF5RSW1Y3rmTW6hx-IcvyToCjlIBiIMizOgVz4jl1DwILtroHeRw1fDtwznbJh1IFN5Y3XtgquX113zK9m0Fv5VFiAsrrHk954A99OQIIQfK5ltPiWP4Z25hdR0fRwjxGK8MCI-t92XUFaM2C87jY4KyOPWFz2E5jJM-SGqPfFT7jfcwx5-SdTyY8zvAFiDyno0TMAjKtmhEXFCDoCAiBk5cswHZcLTNki5ynRtLPJWIABE4yCBk-ga1zY0nRrcz666XmIZrnam7m0WUxrADMGuaDkwwMcBmsscp+uofcn2dlCBTSx0QA)

If you take a look at `formattedData` you will see 7 suggestions. But i only want the `formatted` data and `time` as suggestion

Comment: What is `Datapoint`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WvE3Ym) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz sure, i added

Comment: But now I don't see the errors you're talking about "Property 'tempConsumption' does not exist on type '{ time: string[]; formattedConsumption: number[]; formattedGeneration: number[]; formattedSelfCoverage: number[]; }'." so it's still not reproducible.  (Oh and please include the example as plaintext; a playground link is a good supplement but does not take the place of having the example as plain text in the question itself.)